# Calling async function in WebView2

Tags: javascript, c#, webview2

I have a WebView2 fully set up and for the most part it works fine. The problem I have is with `ExecuteScriptAsync`. If an async JavaScript function is called I get an empty JSON Object `"{}"` as the return value. E.g.:

```
// C#
// this returns the value as expected: '{"foo":true}'
var foo = await webView.CoreWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("(() => { const foo = true; return foo })();");
// on the other hand, this does not: '{}'
var bar = await webView.CoreWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("(async () => { const bar = await myAsyncJsFunction(); return bar; })()";
```

How could I get the return value of an async function call with `ExecuteScriptAsync`?

Edit:
I forgot to await in the JavaScript call. I fixed my code according to @Nick's answer:

```
var bar = await webView.CoreWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("await (async () => { const bar = await myAsyncJsFunction(); return bar; })()";
```

After the fix I got the string `"null"` as the return value. Expecting something is wrong in my function I changed the call like so:

```
 var bar = await webView.CoreWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("await (async () => { const bar = true; return bar; })()";
```

but still I get `"null"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to await your async function is JavaScript:

```
var bar = await webView.CoreWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("await (async () => { const bar = await myAsyncJsFunction(); return bar; })()";
```

Otherwise, you just fire and forget the JS call and it returns to ExecuteScriptAsync immediately.

Comment: Clearly this is correct. But still there is something wrong. Please take a look at the updated question.